# No engine can be assigned to this scan (CheckMarx)

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, checkmarx

While running a pipeline in Azure, to perform a CheckMarx Scan, if I include don't add there is a field in the pipeline form called "Include/Exclude Wildcard Patterns", if I let it by default, o if I excluded a spesific folder it will give the error "No engine can be assigned to this scan"

[image]

I have to spesify the desired folders to the scan....but there is a spesific folder that, if included causes the same error, and I need that folder to be included in the scan, the only thing that the error says is: "No engine can be assigned to this scan", I haven't found documentation about this error